# Transform CSS styling won't work in when clicking on the arrow left Icon on the back of the card

Tags: css

How do you make the card to transform back to the front card when you click on the return arrow left icon at the back of this card both on mobile and desktop device., https://www.besocialscene.com/new-sept-homepage?hs_preview=YhTtsyAc-13258353405

Here are the breakpoints

```
@media (min-width:1025px)  {
 .more {
  display: none;
}
 .card:hover  .content {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

}

```
@media only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 320px) 
 and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  .more {
    display: none;
  }
  .more:checked ~ .content {
   transform: rotateY(180deg) !important;
  }
  .card:hover .content {
   transform: rotateY(180deg) !important;
  }
 }
```

This is the html for the return icon

```
    <label for="card1" class="button return" aria-hidden="true"> 
     <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>                        
    </label>
```

Comment: your example link is working in mobile as well as desktop devices. Please be specific with your issues.

Comment: It s working on Opera.

Comment: Working here as well. Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: sorry that was the old fiddle , this is the actual link of the cards https://www.besocialscene.com/new-sept-homepage?hs_preview=YhTtsyAc-13258353405